# select and count fields

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I would like to return following things:

- What is the LAST field in the database where 'Peter' is in the column 'users'? Return the date.
- How often is the user 'Peter' listed in the column
  'users'. Return an integer.

This is what I have so far:

```
$user = 'Peter';
$myrows = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT users, date FROM yc_customers WHERE users = $user");

foreach ($myrows as $myrow) {
    // Do something here
}
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: you want to use aggregate functions.  `SELECT users, count(users), date FROM yc_customers WHERE users = $user GROUP BY users`   For the date, you could sort by date desc and limit 1.  Or you can do the whole thing in one query with a subquery

Comment: this `$user` is a string; treat it as such and quote it.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 $myrows = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT users, MAX(date), COUNT(*) 
                           FROM yc_customers 
                           WHERE users = '$user' 
                           GROUP BY users");
```

Comment: *try* belongs in comments or as an additional method if one may fail. Give them an explanation "why" they should as well as why their present code may be failing.